# Is it possible to use a subselect in a CASE expression with db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to run the below query on a db2 database.

```
SELECT 
    columnA,
    (CASE  
        WHEN columnA NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT columnC FROM table_2) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) AS columnB
FROM
    table_1;
```

This is producing the error `SQL0115 - Comparison operator NOT not valid`. There are no errors if I replace the subselect with values that I know it will produce.

```
SELECT 
    columnA,
    (CASE  
        WHEN columnA NOT IN ('ABC', 'EFG') THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END) AS columnB
FROM
    table_1;
```

Is it possible to use a subselect for a CASE expression with db2?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be fine, but the `distinct` is not necessary:

```
SELECT columnA,
       (CASE WHEN columnA NOT IN (SELECT columnC FROM table_2) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS columnB
FROM table_1;
```

I would, however, write it using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT columnA,
       (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t2.columnC = t1.columnA)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS columnB
FROM table_1 t1;
```

`NOT IN` will not work as you expect when any of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`.

You can also move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT columnA,
       (CASE WHEN t2.columnC IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS columnB
FROM table_1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT columnC
      FROM table_2
     ) t2
     ON t2.columnC = t1.columnA
```